# Setting up infinite scroll for tabular display of data and rendering only a small subset of data

Tags: javascript, html, django-templates, frontend, infinite-scroll

I am working on a project that fetches at least 50,000 data sets that have to be displayed as tabular data. The data sets are fetched from our MySQL database. The users have the following requirements...

1. The users don't want to set up pagination but they want to render more and more table rows as they scroll down the page.
2. If they scroll up, the users should not see the table rows that were previously displayed when they scrolled down. That means that I have to either delete the table rows that were previously created or hide them.
3. The lag or load time so as to not detect any obvious latency or lag.

Our project uses a LAMP (Python) stack with Django as a framework. We use Django templates which are server side templates. I don't know how to translate the same experience to client side. I have an idea for an approach, can someone either validate it or correct it?

My intended approach is given below:

1. Fetch a certain subset of rows of the original data set upon load (say 5000). This will be cached server side with memcached. On page load, only a certain subset of it (say 100) will be displayed. Each page will have certain state associated with such as page number or page size. These will be initialized using HTML5 history pushstate API.
2. When an ajax request is made, then additional data sets will be fetched and additional table rows will be appended to the existing table rows.
3. When the user scrolls up and reaches what would have been a previous page, the table rows get deleted or hidden.

I don't know how to implement step 3. What event should I listen to? What preconditions should I check for in order to trigger step 3. I also don't know if step 2 is the correct approach.

Comment: Do you want rows that is scrolled out of bounds to disappear immediately? (Maybe you've solved this by now?)

Comment: I have not solved it yet. The effort was deprioritized.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

1. Add a class (`scrolled-past`) to any row that is scrolled past the window top. (If you're using jQuery, [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) is a great tool to detect this.)
2. Fetch more data when reaching bottom.
3. When the data has been fetched, hide all `.scrolled-past` elements, append new rows and scroll to the top of the table (where to first row now is the one that was previously the uppermost visible row).

There might be glitches when hiding, appending and scrolling, but I bet you'll nail it with an hour of tweaking. Adding the exact top offset of the uppermost visible row to the scroll offset in step 3 is one way of making it more neat.

Comment: how do you check if you have scrolled past the row? Sorry, I am bit of a JS novice.

Comment: Either you use a plugin such as jQuery Waypoints, or you do it like this: 1) Set up a timer using ``setInterval(func, delay)``. 2) In the setInterval callback function, iterate all rows, and for each row that has a top offset less than the window's scroll offset, add the class.